# Quelles expériences s'utilisent sans l'article partitif ?

Tags: partitif

Il y a des fois où, pour la description d'une expérience ou émotion, on n'utilise pas l'article partitif, par exemple:

> J'ai peur.
>
> J'ai chaud.

Alors, j'ai été surpris quand j'ai vu

> J'ai de la chance

sur Google. C'est quoi, la propriété sémantique telle que *peur* est comme *chaud* mais n'est pas comme *chance* ?

Comment: Déjà il faut éliminer *chaud* de la liste : *chaud* est un adjectif, *chance* et *peur* sont des noms. Avec un adjectif sans nom l'emploi de l'article ne se pose pas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans le cas de *avoir chaud*, il ne pourrait pas y avoir d'article car *chaud* est (il me semble) utilisé comme adjectif ou adverbe. Cette construction avoir + adjectif/adverbe (sans autre complément) est cela dit inhabituelle et ne se retrouve que dans quelques expressions figées comme *avoir chaud* et *avoir froid*.

Pour *avoir peur* et d'autres (*avoir faim*, *avoir soif*), il y a bien un nom commun qui peut justifier de mettre un article : « avoir de la peur », « avoir de la faim », ces formulations seraient compréhensibles mais sont totalement inusitées, l'usage ayant retenu des formulations figées sans article à la place.

En fait, **il n'y a pas de règle** pour savoir quand on enlève l'article, **il n'y a que des expressions idiomatiques** : dans la construction verbe + nom, en principe on utilise un article, partitif si le nom est indénombrable (*avoir de la chance*, *avoir du charme*, *manger du fromage*), mais il y a des expressions courantes que l'usage a figées sans.

À titre d'exemple, [cette page](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/I_a_article.htm) donne une liste indicative d'expressions idiomatiques formées d'un verbe et d'un nom sans article :

> - *avoir peur*
> - *avoir faim*
> - *avoir soif*
> - *donner ordre*
> - *perdre patience*
> - *prendre congé*
> - *faire attention*
> - *garder rancune*
> - *rendre justice*
> - *tenir parole*
> - *demander pardon*
> - *chercher noise*
> - *donner congé*
> - *avoir à cœur*
> - *aller à cheval*
> - etc.

D'autres encore me viennent à l'esprit : *avoir/faire mal*, *prendre/donner froid/chaud*, *donner faim/soif*, *avoir/faire/prendre pitié/peur*, *rendre compte/service/visite/grâce*, *procurer satisfaction*, *avoir peine*, *avoir besoin de*, *avoir/prendre soin de*, *avoir/donner foi en*, *avoir accès à*, ... Il doit y en avoir beaucoup, sans vraiment de moyen de les identifier à l'avance ; et par exemple bien qu'on puisse *porter chance/bonheur*, jamais on ne dira « avoir chance » ou « procurer bonheur ».